# Why is my latch circuit not toggling?

Tags: transistors, relay, latch

[image]

While I am waiting on some parts I made this circuit in a simulator. When S1 is pressed it should toggle the relay K1 and latch in that state, turning on the other LED. When I press the switch, though, it does not change the relay state. Before I assume an issue with the simulation software, is the circuit itself correct?

S1 open:

[image]

S2 closed:

[image]

So just looking at the LED when S1 is toggled it does turn on, but the state does not latch. It turns off when S1 is released.

Comment: Where did the circuit come from? Can't you look at the various node voltages and see if the circuit is doing what it is supposed to do?

Comment: How quickly are you pressing S1? That circuit won't work if you press it faster than about once per second.

Comment: It also won't work with a one ohm relay - it needs at least several hundred ohms

Comment: I found it here:https://www.edn.com/latching-power-switch-uses-momentary-pushbutton/

Comment: How much current is the LED using?  Could need a current-limiting resistor. Might have to take the output node and further buffer that, with an NMOSFET perhaps (to drive something with lots of current without affecting the rest of the circuit.)

Comment: You MUST use a resistor in series with the LED or the collector of Q2 won't get to the voltage level it needs to charge up C1.

Comment: Would the downvoter PLEASE explain why.

Answer (score 0):

A standard 'impulse relay' alone would suffice for your application. It's also known as a 'ratchet relay'.

The relay could be set and reset with alternate pulses to the coil.